# How to specify the image's size for the left-image of a button?

Tags: android, android-button

I would like to put an image on a `Button` with some text, like:

```
--------------
[image] [text]
--------------
```

We can do this with `Button`, and specify the left `Drawable`, but it uses the `"intrinsic"` size of the drawable. If I understand correctly, this won't work across different density devices. If my image is `32x32` pixels, it will look really small on `hdpi` devices. Is there any way to specify the width and height of the drawable, in `dp`, so that it will take the same amount of space on different devices?

Answer (score 2):

This is correct.  You need an hdpi, mdpi and ldpi version of the image and you just place them in the appropriate drawable folder and the OS will take care of the rest.

Here is a [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) to the resource scheme in case you need more info.